# Handle error codes (401, 403) with Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am building an app using Restangular. I would implement in one place handling of errors like 401, 403, 500 etc in a response interceptor.

This is what I wrote:

```
RestangularProvider.setResponseExtractor(function(response, operation, what, url) {
  switch(response.meta.code) {
    case 200:
      // Handle 200
    break;

    case 401:
      // Redirect to login
    break;

    /* ... */

    default:
    break;
  }
}
```

What actually happens it's that the 200 is correctly *seen* but this method is not hit at all for the 401. 
The JSON I get from server side it is formatted like this for successful responses:

```
{"meta":{"apiVersion":"0.1","code":200,"errors":null},"response":{"response":"value"}}
```

and

```
{"meta":{"apiVersion":"0.1","code":401,"errors":[{"code":401,"message":"Unauthorized"}]},"response":null}
```

for errors. The response header contains the `Status Code:401 Unauthorized` as well.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

401 and any error code will hit the errorInterceptor, not the responseInterceptor. responseInterceptor is only called with successful responses!

Comment: on the errorInterceptor, i am getting the complete response, i.e. with headers etc and the same gets returned to my error hook. Is there any way I can extract the data and return that only? 

I am trying to return the data from the errorInterceptor but still i receive the complete response in my error hook.

Comment: Just to clarify - all 4xx or 5xx status codes use errorInterceptor, and all other status codes use responseInterceptor - is that correct?